# how to convert a statement with auto into one which uses types

Tags: c++, c++17

I prefer to use type, however I am struggling to get the types correct and in the one line for the following auto statement within my code.

In particular the line my_struct.get_map::const_iterator.begin() seems to be an issue.

```
auto selected_node = std::next(my_struct.get_map.begin(), selected_item_index); // working
std::pair<std::string, std::string> selected_node = std::next(my_struct.get_map::const_iterator.begin(), selected_item_index); // not working
```

Comment: Which particular type did you try? Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please. I also have no clue, why you don't want to use `auto`, any specific reasoning for that?

Comment: *"I am struggling to get the types correct"* - this is one reason `auto` was introduced. It allows the programmer to use convoluted return types much more easily.

Comment: [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) returns an *iterator*, not an object of your map

Comment: It's (probably) `decltype(my_struct.get_map)::iterator`. Further information is still on your side.

Comment: The `std::next` returns an iterator. In your case the type is the same as the return type of `my_struct.get_map.begin()`. Without knowing what type the `get_map` variable is we cannot help you.

Comment: You should use an IDE that displays hints on the deduced type of selected_node

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to declare iterator of map? Replace auto by iterator. For example, if your map (get_map return) is map< string,string > then replace auto by `map< string,string >::iterator it`